# Multiple cython consumers of same c library

Tags: c, cython, gmp

I want to work with sage and an external c library. The external library already has python bindings written in cython and handles conversion between python's number classes and gmp integers.

To adapt this to work with sage I want to bypass that conversion: sage integers use gmp under the hood already. But to make my code compile (and work) I used explicit type casts everywhere and I think there should be a better way of doing this. If I can neaten up the code I want to upstream it to sage eventually.

In sage, the gmp bindings for the integer type (`mpz_t`) are declared in a `pxd` file thus:

```
ctypedef struct __mpz_struct:
    int _mp_alloc
    int _mp_size
    mp_ptr _mp_d

ctypedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1]
```

but the external library has its own `pxd` for gmp and declares:

```
ctypedef struct mpz_t:
    pass
```

Manually casting between `sage.mpz_t` and `mylib.mpz_t` all over my code is working fine, but wouldn't it be much better to rewrite the bindings to mylib to use sage's gmp bindings rather than its own? I think so, but how?

There are also inconsistencies between function signatures in gmp, e.g. in sage:

```
void mpz_set (mpz_t rop, mpz_t op)
```

but in mylib, a wild `const` appears:

```
void mpz_set(mpz_t rop, const mpz_t op)
```

I have an inkling that the difference between sage and mylib is that mylib sees `mpz_t` as an opaque struct, but sage delves into the implementation. I have no real experience with low-level C, so any references to material I can use to educate myself on this stuff would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The differences in signature are not something you need to worry about - for `cdef extern` declarations Cython only needs to know enough to correctly call the C code. Therefore the presence/absence of a `const` makes little difference to Cython. Similarly, it isn't necessary to declare all the fields in the struct if you don't use them from Cython.

If you're prepared to change the "mylib" code to use the sage declarations then this is easy - just use `cimport`. I believe the correct import should be

```
from sage.libs.gmp.types cimport mpz_t
```

(This relies on the sage .pxd files being installed on the Python path.) Do something similar for the functions you want to use.

Comment: The first thing I tried was replacing all the `mylib.mpz_t` with `sage.mpz_t` (and used the requisite `cimport sage.libs.gmp.all as sage`) but got a lot of compile errors, including `function cannot return array`, so I went with importing both sets of bindings and adding type casts.

Comment: I've had a look at the gmp source code and the array declaration of `mpz_t` is correct. This does mean it isn't actually possible to return an `mpz_t` from a function. If you're managing to do it by type-casts then I'd be a bit worried that you'll hit undefined behaviour.